# Is there a way to implement GridView on jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

We have AdapterList for listview, so any similar methods like that for implementing GridView

Answer (score 4):

Someone asked same question yesterday on Twitter and this was answer from Leland Richardson

"We had a Table Layout earlier on but it got "de-scoped" for alpha so we removed it. We will likely have a solid/robust one at some point in the future but in the meantime i'm hoping someone makes their own and open sources it. custom layouts are way easier than you'd think"